Allow users to manage some options without granting 'manage_options' capability
I don't want to grant the 'manage_options' capability to all of my users, but I want to give them the access to manage some.
Is it possible to create something like 'my_custom_capability' to access the only pages/options I set? The options I want to access are in some external plugins, so I'm not allowed to edit those plugins.

you can create a page with a custom capability with https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/. then you send the form of this page to admin-post.php and you test again the capability of the current user before to set the values.
